# why an enum value can not be used as a rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, move, rvalue

## Note:

The problem has been solved. It is a bug of `Clion 1.2.4` but **not the compiler**. I can compile the application even if the static-analysis tool of Clion still give me an error.

---

I am using `Clion 1.2.4` to build a `C++` project based on `C++11`, when I try use `make_shared` function to create a `shared_ptr` object like this:

```
auto item = std::make_shared<Type>(EnumType::Value);
```

where `Type` is an struct with a constructor like this:

```
Type(EnumType t = defaultValue) { }
```

and the param of constructor is an **enum** type.

But Clion give me an *error* :

```
parameter type mismatch: Expression must be rvalue.
```

So I want to know whether an enum value can be used as a rvalue to call a function? And why.

---

And if I use like this:

```
auto item = std::make_shared<Type>(std::move(EnumType::Value));
```

Clion will not show the error. What the `move` function do? And is it right that using a constant value as the actual parameter of `move` function.

### Update 2016-01-31:

Thank @[NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver) for the reminder. An simple example can be see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79141096c1a93b7c) (create by NathanOliver).

The following is result of command `gcc -v`:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Can you pleae add an [mcve].  I can get it to compile in [this simple example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/79141096c1a93b7c)

Comment: This probably is bug in compiler, since GCC [compiles it fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b27e9fd976b710cc) with both `enum` and `enum class`.

Comment: Your code is fine; this is a bug in CLion.

Comment: Which compiler are you using? CLion is an IDE

Comment: Clion 1.2.4 is not a compiler but IDE with support for GCC and clang. Thus, seems that old version of compiler is used.